# Multiple Model Associations to same table

Tags: cakephp, model-associations

My situation: I want to bring a HABTM and a hasOne relation working in the same model. unfortunatelly its not loading the groupleaders userinformation into the usergroups.

- a user can have multiple usergroups
- **a usergroup can have one groupleader (user id)**

any help apreciated

I'm having a table layout like this:

---

**users**

```
id
username
```

**user_usergroups**

```
id
user_id
usergroup_id
```

**usergroups**

```
id
groupname
groupleader (value is user_id)
```

---

**usergroups model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'Users',
        'foreignKey' => 'usergroup_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
    )
);


public $hasOne = array(
    'GroupLeader' => array( 'className' => 'User',
    'foreignKey' => 'usergroup_groupleader' )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following was missing in the controller

```
$this->Staffgroup->recursive = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'User' => array(
    'className' => 'Users',
    'joinTable'=>'user_usergroups',
    'foreignKey' => 'usergroup_id',
    'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id'
)
```

);

now when you retrieve information in usersgroup controller , it will contain information of User-group leaders.

Comment: my problem is about the hasOne relation, not the HABTM relation